# Hide (not remove) category name globally on wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to hide a specific category name (e.g. called "Featured") on my whole wordpress blog. Please note I do not want to exclude a post that belongs to that specific category, I only want to prevent the actual category name from showing up anywhre, it should be invisible.

I found a code snippet which I put in my functions.php, and actually it does exactly what I want, but it's only hiding category names from the post meta section, it doesn't have any effect on third party plugins where category name is still showing. Can you please help in order to get this worked for a specific plugin?

Code in function.php for hiding category name:

```
function the_category_filter($thelist,$separator=' ') {
if(!defined('WP_ADMIN')) {

    $exclude = array('featured');
    $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
    $newlist = array();
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));
        if(!in_array($catname,$exclude))
            $newlist[] = $cat;
    }
    return implode($separator,$newlist);
} else
    return $thelist;
}
add_filter('the_category','the_category_filter',10,2);
```

Plungin's function looks like this:

```
private function generate_post_categories( $post ) {

    // Setting up category list string.
    $post_cat_string = '';

    // Setting up category list.
    $post_cat_list = '';

    // Fetching post category prefix  with WPML support.
    $post_category_prefix = ($this->icl_t) ? icl_t('ORP Post Category Prefix', 'post-category-prefix–' . $this->widget_id, $this->widget_args['post_category_prefix'] ) : $this->widget_args['post_category_prefix'];

    // Checking for post category PREFIX.
    if ( !empty( $this->widget_args['post_category_prefix'] ) ) {

        // Building post category PREFIX HTML.
        $post_cat_string .= esc_html( $post_category_prefix );
    }

    // Retrieving categories array.
    $orp_categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );

    // Checking if "post category link" option is on.
    if ( 'yes' == $this->widget_args['post_category_link'] ) {

        // Looping through categories array.
        foreach( $orp_categories as $orp_cat ) {

            // Fetching the current category link.
            $orp_category_link = get_category_link( $orp_cat->cat_ID );

            // Building HTML link atts.
            $linkatts = array(
                'href'  => $orp_category_link,
                'title' => $orp_cat->cat_name
            );

            // Building category link HTML.
            $post_cat_list .= $this->orp_create_tag( 'a', $orp_cat->cat_name, $linkatts ) . esc_html( $this->widget_args['post_category_separator'] );
        }

    } else {

        // Looping through categories array.
        foreach( $orp_categories as $orp_cat ) {

            // Filling categories list.
            $post_cat_list .= $orp_cat->cat_name . esc_html( $this->widget_args['post_category_separator'] );
        }
    }

    // Right trimming the last category separator on the category list.
    $post_cat_string .= rtrim( $post_cat_list, esc_html( $this->widget_args['post_category_separator'] ) );

    // Returning the post category HTML.
    return $this->orp_create_tag( 'div', $post_cat_string, array( 'class' => 'orp-post-category' ) );
```

Comment: You have to see how the category name is displayed in the plugins.

Comment: This is how category is displayed in the plugin: `$new = $this->generate_post_categories( $recent_posts->post );
$orp_content .= $new;`

Comment: `generate_post_categories` is one of the plugin function, you should look into it.

Comment: Found the function, but I don't know what to look for, and which variable I have to replace in the code above. Is this the line I'm looking for?  `$linkatts = array(
     'href'  => $orp_category_link,
     'title' => $orp_cat->cat_name
    );`

Comment: Here it is - it get the category name from the category object, so it doesn't get through `the_category` filter. I suggest you to edit you question to add the code from `generate_post_categories` and from where it is called too, in order to see where we could add a condition.

Comment: thanks, I edited the start post with the plugin's function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to change this part:

```
// Looping through categories array.
foreach( $orp_categories as $orp_cat ) {
```

To :

```
// Looping through categories array.
foreach( $orp_categories as $orp_cat ) {
  if($orp_cat->cat_name == 'Featured') {
    continue;
  }
```

That should skip the loop if the category name is equal to "Featured".

Comment: Sir, that did it. I'm very thankful for your help and would upvote, if I could ;)

Comment: Happy it fixed it ;) If it resolved your issue you can accept the answer by click on the green check on the left :)

Comment: Did so. Thanks again ;)